# Swing: How to achieve forwarding of all events from subcomponents to parent container?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, events

I'm looking for a straightforward way to make a **Swing component forward all received
events to its parent container** (or even all parents up to root).

**EDIT**:
Where do I need this? I have a diagram editor. Components must forward key press and
mouse clicks (to set themselves as "active" as soon as the user clicks a subelement
of that component).

First, let me present my existing solution for this. It's a bit of a workaround.

```
public interface IUiAction {
 void perform(Component c);
}

public static void performRecursiveUiAction(Container parent, IUiAction action) {
 if (parent == null) {
  return;
 }

 for (Component c : parent.getComponents()) {
  if (c != null) {
   action.perform(c);
  }
 }

 for (Component c : parent.getComponents()) {
  if (c instanceof Container) {
   performRecursiveUiAction((Container) c, action);
  }
 }
}

/**
* 1) Add listener to container and all existing components (recursively).
* 2) By adding a ContainerListener to container, ensure that all further added
* components will also get the desired listener.
*
* Useful example: Ensure that every component in the whole component
* tree will react on mouse click.
*/
public static void addPermanentListenerRecursively(Container container,
  final IUiAction adder) {

 final ContainerListener addingListener = new ContainerAdapter() {
  @Override
  public void componentAdded(ContainerEvent e) {
   adder.perform(e.getChild());
  }
 };

 // step 1)
 performRecursiveUiAction(container, adder);

 // step 2)
 performRecursiveUiAction(container, new IUiAction() {
  @Override
  public void perform(Component c) {
   if (c instanceof Container) {
    ((Container) c).addContainerListener(addingListener);
   }
  }
 });
}
```

Usage:

```
addPermanentListenerRecursively(someContainer,
  new IUiAction(
    @Override
    public void perform(Component c){
      c.addMouseListener(somePermanentMouseListener);
    }
  )
);
```

By looking over the code, would you say it's a good concept?
The problem with my current concept is: It's forwarding only events, for which a listener was specified manually.

Can you suggest a better one?

Comment: I encountered the consume() method on some swing events which is used to indicate you consumed the event in your handler. I think the opposite is what you need.

Comment: For example: Mouse click, mouse drag (to "activate" a visual diagram element), all kinds of hot keys, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like it would get a bit tricky if every component in your view handled the same mouse event. ie, if the user drags *item 1*, *item 2* would process those events as well? if i understand correctly, you are looking to have `this` and `this.parent` and `this.parent.parent` handle mouse actions on `this`.  in that case the recursion would be up, and not down.

you could create an `Interface` like this:

```
public interface MyInterface() {
   public void performSpecialAction(Event event);
}
```

you then have your containers implement this interface.  your components would then need to incorporate this call to their appropriate event handling:

```
public static void performRecursiveUiAction(Component comp, Event event) {
  if (comp.getParent() == null) {
     return;
  }
  if (comp.getParent() instanceof MyInteface) {
     ((MyInterface)comp.getParent()).performSpecialAction(event);
  }
  ThisUtility.performRecursiveUiAction(comp.getParent(), event);
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Based on your scenario I have a suggestion for the keyboard side of things:

You could use the KeyStroke facility of swing for that:

```
JRootPane rp = getRootPane();

KeyStroke ks = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F2, 0, false);
rp.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(ks, "F2");
rp.getActionMap().put("F2", new AbstractAction() { 
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { onF2Action(); } });
```

This way you can register 'global' event handlers for shortcuts<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1</sup> although it might have some limitations in your case.

For the mouse-event case I would create a recursive function, which adds a `MouseAdapter` instance to every targeted component. For example:

```
void addToAll(Container c, MouseAdapter a) {
    for (Component p : c.getComponents()) {
        if (p instanceof InterrestingComponent) {
            p.addMouseListener(a);
            p.addMouseMotionListener(a);
            p.addMouseWheelListener(a);
        } else
        if (p instanceof Container) {
            addToAll((Container)p, a);
        }
    }
}
```

Just to capture the concept. You might need different or multiple receivers for various components.

**Edit:** Sorry, I accidentally said WindowAdapter instead of MouseAdapter.

Comment: On a sidenote: One of the good things about Swing in contrary to Delphi that it makes you easy to inject multiple event handlers practivally everywhere you want, whereas Delphi's GUI model was based on single the onSomething approach in my time.

Answer (score 1):

- Either you get the events from the components, and in this case you register the listeners where you need to capture events. Pro is that you can select where to capture events, and you have the choice to receive them selectively by source. Con is that you have to register as much listener as much source you have...
- Or use the glass pane, and capture all before it propagates to components. In this case you capture them all, and you must write custom handling code if you want to tie them to components under the glass pane. (Assuming you kept your glass pane empty...) Here is an example that captures events before it reaches the components, and even forwards it to selected ones: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html#glasspane
- Middle ground is to use the layered pane to create transparent components (glasspane like things) above whatever you need.

Also you can consume() events too... Your main problem is a tradeoff that you either capture events before swing handles (and write custom handling from scratch) them or after (and have some interference from the handling you might have to hack around), but you can't modify the handling code itself by subclassing anything (or can you? never seen so far...).