# Forward all key events to parent JFrame

Tags: java, swing, events, key-events

I need that all the key events (including Carriage Return, TAB, etc) generated by all child or grandchildren components of a JFrame, to be listened for a single method inside this JFrame. I have googled a lot, but I have not been able to find the solution I need. I found a partial solution using "InputMap/ActionMap", but it only allows to add particular KeyStrokes on the InputMap, but I need all possible Key Strokes to be forwarded to the parent JFrame.

Thanks.

(I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052893/swing-how-to-achieve-forwarding-of-all-events-from-subcomponents-to-parent-cont) thread, but I was expecting a solution within the Swing API, specifically to address this subject.

Comment: What do you mean by _all_ possible key strokes? Can you show your attempt with key bindings using input/action map that isn't working? Also, see [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html#api) for a proper tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Global Event Listeners](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/08/30/global-event-listeners/) which gives you a couple of choices:

1. Use an `AWTEventListener`.
2. Us a `KeyEventPostProcessor`.