# Is there a way in swing to capture all keyboard input regardless of focus

Tags: java, swing

## The problem

In Swing (Java), I want to capture all keyboard input, **regardless of which control has focus**.

So, if I press a key on my keyboard (not just alphanumeric, function keys and such included), while the window is in focus, a callback should run, allowing me to do what I want with the given input.

### What I've tried

Using the panel I've tried to add a key listener, which implements the `KeyListener` class in `java.awt.event`, like so:

```java
// MainApplicationWindow.java
// ...
mPanel.addKeyListener(
    new SwingKeyListener()
);
```

With the actual listener being:

```java
// SwingKeyListener.java
public class SwingKeyListener implements KeyListener {

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {/*...*/}

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {/*...*/}

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {/*...*/}
}
```

### Results

GUI is displayed, no errors or exceptions are outputted, key listener does not work.

### Solutions

Solution was to use the `KeyEventPostProcessor` class to poll for input.

```java
KeyEventPostProcessor pp = e -> {
    SwingKeyListener.keyPressed(e);
    return true;
};
DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventPostProcessor(pp);
```

Comment: Add the listener to the Frame

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23613813/forward-all-key-events-to-parent-jframe/23616040#23616040